# Best thing to do about projects supporting multiple versions of Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compatibility

I have an open source project that works on .Net 2.0 and up. The thing is though that I prefer to use Visual Studio 2012, which forces the solution and project files to only work with VS2010/2012.

What exactly should I do? I don't want for my users to have to create a solution from scratch if they don't have access to VS2010, but yet, I also don't want to attempt to keep 3 different project files in sync(VS2005, VS2008, and VS2010/2012)

What is the usual solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the usual solution for this?

Try to `split your source project to versions`. (v1.0- VS08 , v2.0 - VS12). You may still keep .NET 2.0 compatible code with VS2008, and name it as version v1.0, while having your next version be compatible with .NET 5.0 framework and named as v3.0.

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question as I understand it. I think @Earlz is asking how to keep the solution file unlinked from the version of IDE he's using.